# c# mat2gray (matlab) function

Tags: c#, matlab, image-processing, grayscale

Anybody know of a image processing library for c# that has a function that works like the [mat2gray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/mat2gray.html) function in matlab?

Thanks.

Comment: Im guessing that it doesnt exist, but it might be somewhat doable to code it in a loop-like-way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
public Bitmap mat2gray(int[,] mat,double? amin = null, double? amax = null){

  var sizex = mat.GetLength(0);
  var sizey = mat.GetLength(1);
  if (!amin.HasValue)
    amin = 0;
  if (!amax.HasValue)
    amax = 1;
  var ret = new Bitmap(sizex,sizey);
   for (int i=0; i< sizex;i++){
    for (int j=0; j< sizey;j++){
      int A = (int)((Math.Round(mat[i,j]-amin.Value)*(255.0/amax.Value))%amax.Value);
      ret.SetPixel(i,j,Color.FromArgb(A,A,A));
    }
}
```

But the amin/amax stuff needs some finetuning

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, if you have access to the MATLAB Builder NE toolbox, is to use `deploytool` to create an .NET interface to mat2gray (or any other MATLAB functionality you'd like to call from C#).  Then you can just wrap up the arguments as MWArray objects, call the .NET wrapper for the MATLAB function, and unwrap the MWArray[] results that are returned.

Answer (score 0):

You could print the exact implementation of MATLAB functions using the type keyword (apart from built-in functions).

```
type mat2gray
```